# Transitioning between two images after a button click within 30 pixels

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, mouseevent, mouselistener

I'm having trouble getting the images to swap out when it is clicked on by the mouse. It's supposed to switch to the "redSmiley.gif" when the image is clicked within 30pixels from any direction and switch back to "happyFace.gif" when it is clicked again. This is my main method.

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import javax.swing.*;

public class Rebound
{
 //-----------------------------------------------------------------
 //  Displays the main frame of the program.
 //-----------------------------------------------------------------
 public static void main (String[] args)
 {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Rebound");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  frame.getContentPane().add(new ReboundPanel());
  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

This is my Panel Class.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ReboundPanel extends JPanel
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private final int WIDTH = 300, HEIGHT = 100;
private final int DELAY = 20, IMAGE_SIZE = 35;

private ImageIcon image;
private Timer timer;
private int x, y, moveX, moveY;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------
//  Sets up the panel, including the timer for the animation.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
public ReboundPanel()
{
  timer = new Timer(DELAY, new ReboundListener());

  image = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("happyFace.gif"));

  x = 0;
  y = 40;
  moveX = moveY = 3;

  setPreferredSize (new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
  setBackground (Color.black);
  timer.start();
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------
//  Draws the image in the current location.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
public void paintComponent (Graphics page)
{
  super.paintComponent (page);
  image.paintIcon (this, page, x, y);
}

//*****************************************************************
//  Represents the action listener for the timer.
//*****************************************************************
private class ReboundListener implements ActionListener
{
  //--------------------------------------------------------------
  //  Updates the position of the image and possibly the direction
  //  of movement whenever the timer fires an action event.
  //--------------------------------------------------------------
  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
  {
     x += moveX;
     y += moveY;

     if (x <= 0 || x >= WIDTH-IMAGE_SIZE)
        moveX = moveX * -1;

     if (y <= 0 || y >= HEIGHT-IMAGE_SIZE)
        moveY = moveY * -1;

     repaint();
  }
}
class MousePressListener implements MouseListener
{
   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event)
   {
       if(event.getX() <= 30 && event.getY() <= 30)
       {
           if(event.getX() <= 30 && event.getY() <= 30)
           {
               image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("redSmiley.gif"));
           }
           else
               image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("happyFace.gif")); 
       }
   }
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) 
   {
       if(event.getX() <= 30 && event.getY() <= 30)
       {
           image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("redSmiley.gif"));
       }
       else
           image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("happyFace.gif"));
   }
   //Empty methods
   public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) 
   {    
   }
   public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) 
   {    
   }
   public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0)
   {
   }
 }
}
```

How do I get the Images to swap when the mouse button is clicked within 30 pixels?

Answer (score 0):

You need to know where the image is been rendered and you need to compare the mouse point against this...

One way would be to create a `java.awt.Rectangle` which includes the buffer...

```
Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle();
bounds.x = x - 30;
bounds.y = y - 30;
bounds.width = image.getWidth(this) + 60;
bounds.height = image.getHeight(this) + 60;
```

Then check to see if the mouse point is within it's boundaries...

```
if (bounds.contains(event.getPoint()) {
    // Did click image...
```